# How to install "Google Wave Protocol" in Windows Computer?

Tags: installation, google-wave

Are there any procedure to install [Google Wave Protocol](https://sites.google.com/a/waveprotocol.org/wave-protocol/code/installation) in my Windows computer?
Note: Microsoft IIS, Apache Server and Java is already installed in my computer.

Comment: I assume you mean install google Gears

Comment: Actually, from the looks of the link, the submitter wants to install Google Wave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of the link you provided, I believe this is only supported on Linux/Unix installations and will not run on Windows.  You could install Linux in a virtual machine and go that route, but what you're trying to do is very difficult, if not impossible, as it was not engineered with Windows servers in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, but soon may be:

[Google Wave Will Live On As Apache Wave](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/google_wave_will_live_on_as_apache_wave.php)

> It looks like December 31, 2010 will not mark the end of Google Wave
>   after all. The Apache Software Foundation, the non-profit organization
>   responsible for supporting Apache open source projects, has accepted
>   Google Wave into its incubator program...